# AutocompletExtender does not fire

Tags: asp.net

I am using Ajaxtoolkit AutoCompleteExtender Control.
My Web Service(.asmx file) is working well but when I am putting letter in TextBox control
it is unable to retrieve data from web service.

My aspx file is

```
<AjaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autocompletedl" BehaviorID="autocomplete"
                                            runat="server" ServiceMethod="GetStoreGroupCompletionList" ServicePath="dealercode.asmx"
                                            MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                            CompletionInterval="300"
                                            CompletionSetCount="10"
                                            EnableCaching ="true"
                                            TargetControlID="txtdcode" CompletionListElementID="completediv">
```

**And My asmx.cs(within App_Code) file is**

```
public string[] GetStoreGroup(string prefixText, int count)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();


    if (dt == null)
    {
        string query = "select Dcode from ftl_tbl_dealer_mast where Dcode like '" + prefixText + "%'";
        dt = dttras.fetchTabledl(query);

    }

    DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("Dcode LIKE '" + prefixText + "%'");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length && i < count; i++)
    {
        results.Add(rows[i]["Dcode"].ToString());
    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's reason, but I can give you a tip:

you can use HTTP detection tool to detect whether browser already sends request to your web service or meets any issues. If you work on Firefox, you can use Firebug plug-in, you can install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Thanks little bit help for debug process thank you very munch..............Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
 ServiceMethod="GetStoreGroupCompletionList"
```

with

```
ServiceMethod="GetStoreGroup"
```